# Having trouble installing predis pear package osx

Tags: php, macos, pear, predis

I am trying to install predis through pear in the osx terminal and getting this error:

```
$ pear install pearhub/predis
Attempting to discover channel "pearhub"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "pearhub"...
unknown channel "pearhub" in "pearhub/predis"
invalid package name/package file "pearhub/predis"
install failed
```

Do you know what I have to do to discover pearhub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PEAR needs to know what "pearhub" means. In this case, it means "pearhub.org", a project repository. Discover like this:

```
$ pear channel-discover pearhub.org
$ pear install pearhub/predis
```

Answer (score 3):

Predis git repository https://github.com/nrk/predis/ contains link to PEAR channel http://pear.nrk.io/ and following instruction here:

1. pear channel-discover pear.nrk.io
2. pear remote-list -c nrk
3. pear install nrk/predis